# Getting a "File$" instead of a File in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am allowing users to grab a profile pic and upload that picture as file to my server, but I'm getting this error when inputting the image via `ImagePickerWeb`:

```
<error>:<getObject: Unexpected error from chrome devtools:>
```

I don't know if it's my browser or me, but this is what I'm trying:

```
  Future<void> getMultipleImageInfos() async {
    var imageFile =
        await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(outputType: ImageType.file);

        print(imageFile);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        currentSelfie = imageFile;

        _accDetails['customer_selfie'] = currentSelfie;
      });
    }
  }
```

Then displaying that photo here:

```dart
Image.file(
  currentSelfie,
  height: screenAwareSize(100, context),
  width: screenAwareSize(100, context),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

Comment: What is the `"File$"` thing you mentioned in the question title?  Where did that come from?

Comment: That comes from imageFile. It comes in that format is "File$" instead of file and I'm not sure how to use that to display my photo or upload data.

Comment: I don't understand what 'It comes in that format is "File$"' means.

Comment: The "it" in this scenario would be the variable "imageFile." After passing it to CurrentSelfie, I am prompted with the message "Error: Expected type File got File$" when displaying the photo.

Comment: Was a solution ever found to this??

Comment: @who-aditya-nawandar there was an update to the Imagepicker web pluggin. You have to update the logic